# Need help displaying sorted array values

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, dynamic, runtime-error

My assignment is to create a program that takes inputs of names and scores from the user and then sorts the scores in descending order using arrays. I believe I have everything figured out except for getting my program to actually display the scores after they have been sorted.

I get no error messages, but when it is time to display the scores, the scores generate endlessly, all with the value of zero. They should stop generating after x number of scores.

Thanks so much.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void initializeArray(string*, int*, int);
void sortData(string*, int*, int);
void displayData(const string*, const int*, int);

int main()
{
    int SIZE;
    string *name;
    name = new string[SIZE];
    int *score;
    score = new int[SIZE];
      initializeArray(name, score, SIZE);
      sortData(name, score, SIZE);
      displayData(name, score, SIZE);
}
void initializeArray(string names[], int scores[], int size)
{
    cout<<"how many scores will you enter? ";
    cin>> size;
    for(int count = 0; count<size; count++)
    {
        cout<<"name number "<<count+1<<": ";
        cin>> names[size];
        cout<<"score number "<<count+1<<": ";
        cin>> *(scores + count);
    }
}
void sortData(string names[], int scores[], int size)
{

    int temp;
    bool swap;

    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for(int count=0; count < (size-1); count++)  
        {
            if(scores[count] > scores[count+1])
            {
                temp = scores[count];
                scores[count] = scores[count+1];
                scores[count+1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    }while(swap);//while there is a bool swap
}
void displayData(const string names[], const int scores[], int size)
{
    for(int count = 0; count<size; count++)  
    {
        cout<<"name "<<count<<": "<< scores[count]<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        //cout<<"score "<<count+1<<": "<< *(scores + count)<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `string *name;` Are you serious? Use `std::vector<std::string>` and be done.

Comment: What if entered `size` is bigger than the `SIZE`, did you think about that?

Answer (score 0):

```
void initializeArray(string names[], int scores[], int size)
{
    cout<<"how many scores will you enter? ";
    cin>> size;
    ...
}
```

Here's at least one problem. The `size` variable is local to the `initializeArray`. The value entered by the user can never be seen outside of this function. Specifically calling this function will not change the value of `SIZE` in main.

If you want the size entered to be visible in the rest of the code you need to pass `size` by reference.

```
void initializeArray(string names[], int scores[], int& size)
{
    cout<<"how many scores will you enter? ";
    cin>> size;
    ...
}
```

That extra `&` is crucial.